# Show that for nonzero integers $x, y$, the inequality $|x^2 - (1+\sqrt{2})^2y^2| \geq 1$ holds.

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to show that for nonzero integers $x, y$, the inequality $|x^2 - (1+\sqrt{2})^2y^2| \geq 1$ holds.

What I have done: I think it is enough to consider positive integers $x, y$, and let $x$ be the integer that is close enough to $(1+\sqrt{2})y$, but I don’t know how to control $|x-(1+\sqrt{2})y|$ in this situation. Can someone help me?

Comment: Where does this interesting question come from?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Well, it comes from an article introducing Oppenheim Conjecture (In Chinese): https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/CgW0ukO08_j28zNEJ5u0CQ. 
And the author mentions this inequality in annotations as a counter example when n = 2, and he says that it is easy to verify this inequality.

Comment: A possible direction to consider is, the closer $\frac{x}{y}$ is a rational approximation of $1+\sqrt{2}$, the smaller the value of $|x^2 - (1+\sqrt{2})^2y^2|$ should be

Comment: Also since $1 = (\sqrt{2} -1)(\sqrt{2}+1)$, a sneaky '*multiply by 1*' trick may be involved

Comment: Maybe this will help. For a positive integers $x, y$: $|x - (1 + \sqrt{2})y| = \frac{|(x-y)^2 - 2y^2|}{x + (\sqrt{2}-1)y} \ge \frac{1}{x + (\sqrt{2}-1)y}$. This is true because $(x - y)^2 = 2y^2$ has no solutions in positive integers.

Comment: @DenisShatrov Thanks! I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but hopefully this stuff will be useful for someone else to reach a complete solution. Also, the minimum I've found from some numerical tests is $x=5, y=2 \rightarrow 1.686$, so unsure if exact $1$ can be achieved.

**Summary**: We are done if we can prove
$$\left| \lfloor x^0(y) \rceil^2 - (x^0(y))^2 \right| \geq 1 \quad \forall \; y \in \mathbb{N}, \quad x^0(y) \equiv (\sqrt{2} + 1)y$$
where $\lfloor x \rceil$ is the value of $x$ rounded to the nearest integer (not sure if there is a standard notation for this).

**Explanation**:
One approach to solve the original question is to find the minimum value of the following, and show it's $\geq 1$
$$\min_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus {0}} f(x,y), \quad f(x,y) \equiv |x^2 - (1+\sqrt{2})^2y^2|$$

As the author noted, $f$ is even in both $x$ and $y$; i.e. $f(x,y) = f(-x,y) = f(x,-y)$. So we can simplify the domain to just natural numbers,
$$\min_{x,y \in \mathbb{N}} f(x,y)$$

Now suppose we relax the integrality requirement on $x$. Then the minimum value is $f(x^0(y),y) = 0$ for any $y \in \mathbb{N}$, where $x^0(y) \equiv (\sqrt{2} + 1)y$. Clearly, $x^0(y)$ will always be irrational for any natural number $y$. So this can never be the solution to the above minimization problem. But if we analyze $f(x,y)$ for a given $y$, we can observe that the value will increase as $x$ moves away from $x^0(y)$. So for a given $y$, the minimum value of $f(x,y)$ when $x$ is also a natural number is the closest integer to $x^0(y)$, which I'm denoting by $\lfloor x^0(y) \rceil$.

Then we don't need to check all pairs of $x$ and $y$; just $\lfloor x^0(y) \rceil$ for every $y$. Then the minimization problem becomes single variable,
$$\min_{y \in \mathbb{N}} f(\lfloor x^0(y) \rceil,y)$$

So one could iterate through all the natural numbers, calculating the value for each and recording the minimum so far. I ran up to $10^6$, and got $y = 2, x^0(y) =4.83, f(\lfloor x^0(y) \rceil,y) = 1.686$.

But let's look at the function itself.
$$f(\lfloor x^0(y) \rceil,y) =  |(\lfloor x^0(y) \rceil)^2 - (1+\sqrt{2})^2y^2| = |(\lfloor x^0(y) \rceil)^2 - (x^0(y))^2 |$$

It's the difference between the square of $x^0(y)$ and the square of the rounded value of $x^0(y)$, and so proportional to the gap between $x^0(y)$ and the nearest integer to it. Let this gap be $\epsilon(y)$, where $\lfloor x^0(y) \rceil = x^0(y) + \epsilon(y)$ and so $-1 \leq \epsilon(y) \leq 1$. Then we get, since $x^0(y) \geq 2$,
$$f(\lfloor x^0(y) \rceil,y) = |\epsilon(y)|\left(2x^0(y) +\epsilon(y)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think that the “1” in the right side of this inequality is because the original condition is that x and y cannot both be zero, and I changed condition for convenience, so it is quite possible that the lower bound can be optimized.

Comment: >  So for a given y, the minimum value of $f(x,y)$ when x is also a natural number is the closest integer to $x^0(y)$, which I'm denoting by $\lfloor x^0(y)\rceil$.

I don't think that follows. Since squaring is convex, $(n+0.5)^2, n \ge 0$ will always be nearer to $n^2$ than $(n+1)^2$. So if the fractional part of $x^0(y)$ is just slightly above $0.5$, the nearest integer (rounded up) will not produce the smallest $f$.

Comment: I also did some munerical tests, and the minimum is still the same until $y=10^9$